# Nginx reverse proxy issue with Ubuntu

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am attempting to build an nginx reverse proxy with Ubuntu that points to another server on the same network. I will not get into the technical details of why this is needed, but it has to do with terminating an overlay VPN network and some restrictions on access to underlying ELB instances in AWS. To configure the reverse proxy, I edited the file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default to the below:

`server {
    listen 80;
    server_name reverse-proxy.example.com;
    location / {
      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_pass          http://proxied-destination.example.com;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;
    }
  }`

Now, when I log in to a separate server from within the network (we are using internal DNS and private IPs here), I test this with `wget reverse-proxy.example.com/api/xyz` and I expect to hit the reverse proxy and then be proxied to proxied-destination.example.com/api/xyz. On the wget, I am receiving a 404 not found. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try put IP address, instead of FQDN. And also you may try using resolver YOUR_INTERNAL_DNS_SERVER directive.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer